# how to determine what x to let in solving inverse trigonometry problem

Tags: trigonometry, inverse

[image: Question Pic]

How do they know that taking x = tan theta will solve the problem?
I have seen such assumption in many question, in some they take x = sec theta etc.
How to determine the x which will solve the problem easily?

Comment: Now try asking it again. A bit politely. Showing your efforts too

Comment: Your question doesn't give much to go off, but for starters that would turn your big gross inverse trig problem into an algebraic problem in terms of theta.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The idea of this change of variable can  result from a  form of "pattern matching":

When I see such a formula with $\tan^{-1}$ of a certain expression containing in particular a subexpression $1+x^2$. As I know by heart a certain number of trigonometrical formulas, among them $1+\tan^2 \theta=\tfrac{1}{cos^2 \theta}$, I do the "matching" (i.e., I make the corresponding change of variables) guided by the fact that a single term is better than two, but "triggered" by the supplementary fact that there is a square root that can be suppressed doing that.

Answer (score 0):

because $\sin^{-1} x$ is an angle. And we are simply denoting it as $\theta$ as convention and it's easier to solve.